# JQuery function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

following code:

```
// also tried function getDeletedDates()
var getDeletedDates = function()
{
    var s = new Array();

    $(".deleted").each(function(i, e) {
        s.push($(e).attr("data-day"));
    });
};

    $(function()
    {
        $("#delete_send").click(function() {
            alert("drin");
            $.ajax({
                  url: "delete.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: ({deleteDates : getDeletedDates()}),
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(msg){
                     alert(msg);
                  },
                  beforeSend: function(){
                      alert("Lösche folgende Urlaubstage: "+ getDeletedDates().join(", "));
                  },
                  error: function(x, s, e) {
                      alert("Fehler: " + s);
                  }
               }
            );
        });
    });
```

But i come into `beforeSend`() he always says "`getDeletedDates`() undefined"
Why is this, i declared the function in global scope?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything, so the result will be undefined. Change the method to return the array.

**UPDATE**:

When you do `getDeletedDates()` it is evaluated to undefined, because of the lack of return result.  This is why `getDeletedDates() is undefined` is the error message.

Comment: ohh thank you this helped,
but I'm confused why it says "getDeletedDates() is undefined"

but thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your function, but the function is defined as a variable/pointer and doesn't return anything. The following modification should work (not tested):

```
function getDeletedDates()
{
    var s = new Array();

    $(".deleted").each(function(i, e) {
        s.push($(e).attr("data-day"));
    });

    return s;
};
```